# Unable to ssh server via ipv6

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, ipv6

First: ipv4 works fine.

So I got the following setup: (Server is an Arch Linux OS running as VM)

**EDIT**
Added a rule

```
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
```

which accepts ANY connection on port 22 (to make sure it's not an IP failure), but that does not work as well. So I am doing something wrong with the `ssh ...` command or the ipv6 firewall table is not working:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                
DROP       all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
UDP        udp      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
TCP        tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp flags:0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
REJECT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain TCP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22

Chain UDP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

---

After deleting the ip6table it finally works :D So I need to figure out what went wrong :)

Comment: Why is there a `%eth0` at the end of your (apparently fake) IPv6 address?

Comment: Just edited it because I've seen that somewhere (its the clients interface). But if I append the eth0 it literally happens nothing (stays in the execution).

Comment: OK, well first, check the firewall on the remote host. That firewall rule you posted above doesn't actually get referenced from anywhere, so it has no effect.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add the reference. Still does not change anything (after restarting the ip6tables.service)

Comment: Well, then, what does your firewall look like?

Comment: Sorry, just added the full table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you didn't go into too much detail about your setup, here are a few pointers:

Verify that...

- you have ip_forward enabled for IPv6: `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`
- you are not dealing with link-local addresses (the fe80::/10 prefix)
- you can access the VM via IPv6 from the host it's running on.
- you test IPv6 connectivity with firewall disabled (`ip6tables -F`) first and add rules when it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my Edgerouter X. I tried to set ssh port with protocols with TCP_UDP, not only TCP, solved the problems. TCP works well with IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

this is for hetzner IPv6 servers, may not be specific to OP's question, but this article is coming on web searches due to the matching question title.

ref: https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/servers/getting-started/connecting-to-the-server/

if the IPv6 address displayed in your hetzner dashboard is like 2a01:2001:db8:1234::/64, then the way we ssh in is by replacing `/64` with `1`

A full command including a specific private ssh key file specified and telling the system to not bother trying the other ssh keys:

```
ssh -6 -i ~/.ssh/keys/hetzner-key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes root@2a01:2001:db8:1234::1
```

in case you have a different user from root then replace `root` above with that username.

This worked for me on my Linux Mint 21.1 Vera OS out of the box, didn't need to change any settings.